# selenium chrome driver httplib.badstatusline

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, xvfb, httplib

I install selenium, chrome, pyvritualdisplay and xvfb using the following tutorial:
https://christopher.su/2015/selenium-chromedriver-ubuntu/

when i try to run a python selenium script i get this error when i call webdriver.Chrome()

I'm using python2.7.6
on Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "selenium_python_unittests/attempt_50.py", line 9, in <module>
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
  File "/home/sele/headless/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 69, in __init__
desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)
  File "/home/sele/headless/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 92, in __init__
self.start_session(desired_capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/home/sele/headless/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 179, in start_session
response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, capabilities)
  File "/home/sele/headless/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 234, in execute
response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
  File "/home/sele/headless/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/remote_connection.py", line 407, in execute
return self._request(command_info[0], url, body=data)
  File "/home/sele/headless/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/remote_connection.py", line 439, in _request
resp = self._conn.getresponse()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1051, in getresponse
response.begin()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 415, in begin
version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 379, in _read_status
raise BadStatusLine(line)
httplib.BadStatusLine: ''
```

Any idea? This doesn't make any sense to me, because this exception happens before I even make a web request to a website

```
driver.get('http://christopher.su')
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Was using an outdated version of chrome driver.

If have this issue, please check if your using latest update of the chromedriver, and the chrome browser. and be sure your using python2+

Thank You.

Comment: `brew install chromedriver` for mac, or see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads

Comment: This is neat, i never knew i could do this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Updating to the new version of Chromedriver (2.26) fixed it for me.

Comment: This should be a comment