# selenium browser error with Chrome

Tags: selenium

I'm getting the following error from selenium:

```
  File "clint-selenium.py", line 58, in <module>
 browser = Chrome()  
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 69, in __init__
    desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 92, in __init__
    self.start_session(desired_capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 179, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, capabilities)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 234, in execute
    response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/remote_connection.py", line 407, in execute
    return self._request(command_info[0], url, body=data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/remote_connection.py", line 439, in _request
    resp = self._conn.getresponse()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1136, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 453, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 417, in _read_status
    raise BadStatusLine(line)
httplib.BadStatusLine: ''
```

I am calling it with code:

```
from contextlib import closing
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome # pip install selenium
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

browser = Chrome()  
browser.get('http://www.google.com')  
time.sleep(1)  
print browser.title  
browser.quit()
```

I have evidently done something to my laptop because this used to work.  Any thoughts

**EDIT**

I've tried updating chromedriver but I'm now getting

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "clint-selenium.py", line 58, in <module>
    browser = Chrome()  
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 69, in __init__
    desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 92, in __init__
    self.start_session(desired_capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 179, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, capabilities)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 236, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 192, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: session not created exception
from unknown error: Runtime.executionContextCreated has invalid 'context': {"auxData":{"frameId":"13524.1","isDefault":true},"id":1,"name":"","origin":"://"}
  (Session info: chrome=54.0.2840.90)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.20.353124 (035346203162d32c80f1dce587c8154a1efa0c3b),platform=Linux 4.4.0-45-generic x86_64)
```

This seems to indicate I'm still not using the latest version.  I've followed a couple of guides about installation and I'm getting the same result.  Any thoughts

Comment: Possible duplicate of [selenium chrome driver httplib.badstatusline](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40292133/selenium-chrome-driver-httplib-badstatusline)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Chromedriver](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/) was apparently updated on 2016-10-22, after which I also encountered this problem. Updating to the new version of Chromedriver (2.25) fixed it for me.

Comment: This seems to be the issue but I'm struggling to get update - please see edit

Comment: Sorted - I was forcing an old version to download